# Simplest Python user registration system?

Tags: python, django, authentication, registration

I am building in Python on django framework. Having done some tutorials, I now want to build a very simple lightweight application.

The first part of my application is that I need a user system. i.e. a way for people to sign up and a way for me to keep their information private.

What is the easiest way for me to set this up?

Any pre-existing code you could point me to? Or any tutorials that you particularly think are good?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[django-registration](https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/) should get you started.